# How do I return only those customers who owe me money (in mySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Customer table and a Payment table that are joined on a customers ID (CID).  In the Payment table there is an Amount column; some rows have a positive amount (they owed money), but others have a negative amount (they paid money).

I want know which customers, when I sum their positive and negative amounts, still owe me money.

If I just wanted to see their balances, I could do that like so:

```
SELECT Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Customer.AccountNumber, SUM(Amount) As Balance
FROM Customer
 JOIN Payment
   ON Customer.CID = Payment.CID
GROUP BY Customer.AccountNumber
```

How do I change this so that if the balance is 0 or less, I don't return a row for that customer?

Edit:  `HAVING` was the keyword I did not know.  Thanks for the many right answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HAVING keyword allows you to select based on group by functions:

```
SELECT Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Customer.AccountNumber, SUM(Amount) As Balance
FROM Customer
JOIN Payment
ON Customer.CID = Payment.CID
GROUP BY Customer.AccountNumber
HAVING SUM(Amount) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Customer.AccountNumber, SUM(Amount) As Balance
FROM Customer
 JOIN Payment
   ON Customer.CID = Payment.CID
GROUP BY Customer.AccountNumber
HAVING Balance>0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.AccountNumber, p.Amount AS Balance
FROM Customer c 
JOIN Payment p
ON c.CID = p.CID
GROUP BY c.AccountNumber
HAVING SUM(p.Amount) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select customers.name, sum(payments.amount) balance  
from customers join payments on customers.id = payments.cid
group by customers.id having balance > 0
```